# Qt set HTML text with JavaScript function return

Tags: javascript, html

I need to fill an html text with the (str) return of a JavaScript function.

My html "code" :

```
<h1> Product name : (I want my str here) </h1>
```

My JavaScript function:

```
function getMenu(which)
{
    var str = bridge.getCurrentMenu(which);
    alert(str);
    return str;
}
```

I know its probably a simple syntax, but can't find it on Google.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a `span` inside your `h1` and than use `javascript` to change

```js
function hi(){
var el = document.getElementById('myspan');
el.innerHTML = getMenu();
}

function getMenu(wich)
{
    //var str = bridge.getCurrentMenu(wich);
    //alert(str);
    return 'Your string';
}
```

```html
<h1> Product name : (<span id="myspan">i want my str here</span>) </h1>

<button onclick="hi()">Replace </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ty for answering, i found another way to do it :

```
<form id="Label">
<div id="label1"></div>
<div>
<form name="Cancel">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    $(div).append(getMenu(2))
          .appendTo('#label1')
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getMenu(wich)
{
    var a = bridge.getCurrentMenu(wich);
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html code should be

```
<h1 id="productHeading"> Product name :  </h1>
```

In your JS,

```
function getMenu(wich)
{
    var str = bridge.getCurrentMenu(wich);
    $('#productHeading').append(''); 
    $('#productHeading').append('Product Heading: ' + str);  
}
```

Explanation:

- I initially said you code should be as said in step one is because incase you wanted to show an empty product name.
- the js code: `$('#productHeading').append('');` makes sure it clears any text in the class 'productHeading'.
- Then you append the required content into your `<h1 class="productHeading">` class with `enter code here`

The reason why I added the id 'productHeading' is to tell JavaScript function that it needs to append the functions returning content to the class name 'productHeading'.